# jQuery calculating average & sorting result

Tags: jquery

I need to add functions using jQuery to:

1. Add row (completed)
2. Calculate average score of input. Replace the "?" in the column.
3. For average score >=8, the line will be highlighted with red.

I am supposed to use each() and children() for last 2 functions. But as a beginner, I find this extremely confusing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var _stt = 1;
  $("#btn-add").click(function() {
    var name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var math = $('input[name="math"]').val();
    var physic = $('input[name="physic"]').val();
    var chemistry = $('input[name="chemistry"]').val();
    var calcdtb = "?";
    var addtr = '<tr> <td>' + _stt + '</td> <td>' + name + '</td> <td class="mark">' + math + '</td> <td class="mark">' + physic + '</td> <td class="mark">' + chemistry + '</td> <td class="result_dtb">' + calcdtb + '</td> </tr>';
    $("#inputtab").append(addtr);
    _stt++;
  });
  $("#btn-average").click(function() {

  })
  $("#btn-sort").click(function() {

  })

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" align="center">
  <h1>Class Marksheet</h1>
  <form style="padding-bottom: 20px">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Math Score</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="math" id="math"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Physics Score</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="physic" id="physic"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Chemistry Score</td>
        <td><input type="number" name="chemistry" id="chemistry"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button type="submit" id="btn-add">Input</button>
</div>
<!--Div Tab for showing data input and calculating average value-->
<div class="tab" align="center" style="padding-top: 10px">
  <table id="inputtab" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
    <th>List</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Math</th>
    <th>Physics</th>
    <th>Chemistry</th>
    <th>Average</th>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" id="btn-average">Average</button>
  <button type="submit" id="btn-sort">Top Student</button>
</div>
```

Comment: too add function?

Comment: No, I just need to figure out average calculating & filtering function (requirement #2 and #3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please study the code for the following:

- Valid HTML (thead/tbody/tfoot)
- how to use the length of children to calculate the row number
- conversion from str to valid number to avoid NaN
- setting and getting data attributes
- adding a string using a ternary (`_calcdtb>8 ? 'class="high"':''`)
- sort by subtracting the avg in cell a from avg in cell b

```js
const makeNum = str => isNaN(str) || str.trim() === "" ? 0 : parseInt(str);
$(function() {
  $("#btn-add").click(function() {
    var _name = $('input[name="name"]').val();
    var _math = makeNum($('input[name="math"]').val());
    var _physic = makeNum($('input[name="physic"]').val());
    var _chemistry = makeNum($('input[name="chemistry"]').val());
    var _calcdtb = (_math + _physic + _chemistry) / 3;
    var _tr = '<tr ' + (_calcdtb >= 8 ? 'class="high"' : '') + '> <td>' + ($("#inputtab").children().length + 1) + '</td> <td>' + _name + '</td> <td class="mark">' + _math + '</td> <td class="mark">' + _physic + '</td> <td class="mark">' + _chemistry + '</td> <td class="result_dtb" data-avg="' + _calcdtb.toFixed(2) + '">?</td> </tr>';
    $("#inputtab").append(_tr);
    $("#inputForm")[0].reset();
  });
  $("#btn-average").on("click", function() {
    $("#inputtab tr td.result_dtb").each(function() {
      this.textContent = this.dataset.avg;
    })
  })
  $("#btn-sort").on("click", function() {
    $('#inputtab tr').sort(function(a, b) {
      return +$('td.result_dtb', b).data('avg') - +$('td.result_dtb', a).data('avg'); 
    }).appendTo('#inputtab')
  })
})

/* if you need to have the total avg here is the code

    const arr = $("#inputtab tr td.result_dtb")
     .map(function() { return +$(this).text() }) // content
     .get(); // as an array
    const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); // summing all values in the array
    const avg = sum/arr.length; // sum divided by number of lines
    $("#avg").text(avg.toFixed(2)); // force 2 decimals
*/
```

```css
tr.high {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" align="center">
  <h1>Class Marksheet</h1>
  <form id="inputForm"style="padding-bottom: 20px">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">Math Score</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="math" id="math"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">Physics Score</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="physic" id="physic"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="100">Chemistry Score</td>
          <td><input type="number" name="chemistry" id="chemistry"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  <button type="button" id="btn-add">Input</button>
</div>
<!--Div Tab for showing data input and calculating average value-->
<div class="tab" align="center" style="padding-top: 10px">
  <table style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
    <thead>
      <th>List</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Math</th>
      <th>Physics</th>
      <th>Chemistry</th>
      <th>Average</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="inputtab"></tbody>
    <!-- tfoot><tr><td colspan="5"></td><td id="avg"></td></tfoot -->
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="btn-average">Average</button>
  <button type="button" id="btn-sort">Top Student</button>
</div>
```

NOTE that in modern browsers you can change

```
var _tr = '<tr '+(_calcdtb >= 8 ? 'class="high"':'')+'> <td>' + ($("#inputtab").children().length+1) + '</td> <td>' + _name + '</td> <td class="mark">' + _math + '</td> <td class="mark">' + _physic + '</td> <td class="mark">' + _chemistry + '</td> <td class="result_dtb" data-avg="'+_calcdtb.toFixed(2) + '">?</td> </tr>';
```

to this (using template literals)

```
var _tr = `<tr ${_calcdtb >= 8 ? 'class="high"':''}>
  <td>${$("#inputtab").children().length+1}</td>
  <td>${_name}</td>
  <td class="mark">${_math}</td>
  <td class="mark">${_physic}</td> 
  <td class="mark">${_chemistry}</td>
  <td class="result_dtb" data-avg="${_calcdtb.toFixed(2)}">?</td>
 </tr>`;
```

which is much easier to read

Comment: This is great. Thank you. However when "Input" is clicked, average column should only ="?". Only after "Average" button is clicked should the "?" be replaced by average number. It's not for the average of the column but the average number of (math + physics + chemistry). I hope it's not too confusing.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any advice for the last button "Top Student"? It shouldn't be coded in CSS but jQuery. Only when the button is clicked, the filter will be applied.

Comment: I've been trying this but it doesn't seem working `$("btn-sort").click(function () {
                $("#inputtab tr td.result_dtb").each(function () {
                    $(".high").css("color", "red")
                })`

Comment: `($("#inputtab").children().length + 1)` --> Also this doesn't work as auto numbering row..

Comment: I’ll look later - I’m not near a computer

Comment: What do you mean by `($("#inputtab").children().length + 1)` does not work? When you sort? It obviously works in the snippet above

Comment: So when you click sort, do you want to sort or just mark the top student?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yeah it's just need to be marked in red. After reading your solution I think this should be possible:
`
$("#btn-sort").click(function () {
                $("#inputtab tr.high").css(
                    "color", "red"
                )
            })
`

Comment: And never mind the first numbering column, I just figured it out by set var list=1; and list++

Comment: I sorted now. Leave the red, the top student is at the top after clicking top student

Comment: The numbering WORKS. Does it not work for you on your computer?
Do not bother adding code to number cells when the script can do it for you

Comment: Just double checked! Script does work. I've learnt a lot from this. Hope to learn more from you! Thank you for helping me!

Comment: By the way.. Is there anyway to clear inputs after button is clicked? I just want to make it look nicer.

Comment: I gave the form an ID and reset it now